# How to copy/transfer key and values from 1 dictionary to another new dictionary/list?

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, grouping, keyvaluepair

I am a beginner to the Key-Value manipulation.
I currently have 2 dictionaries.First dictionary with the original key and value.

```
var firstDict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
```

- key:a ,value: 1
- key:b ,value: 2
- key:c ,value: 1
- key:d ,value: 3
- key:e ,value: 5
- key:f ,value: 1
- key:g ,value: 4
- key:h ,value: 2
- key:i ,value: 1
- key:j ,value: 2

And below is my second dictionary.

```
Dictionary<int, string> secondDict = firstDict
         .GroupBy(k => k.Value)
         .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => string.Join(",", g.Select(k => k.Key)));
```

This is what **second dictionary** prints.

- key **1** : values : **a,c,f,i**
- key **2** : values : **b,h,j** **...**

So what I want to do now is to ***separate each*** key-value(s) from the **second dictionary** and create dynamic dictionaries/lists to store them if they satisfy some conditions `if(kv.Value > 3){store in new Dictionary}`

Key_1_Dict

> a,c,f,i

Key_2_Dict

> b,h,j

Key_3_Dict  ......

May I know if there is a way to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood your point, you can use *Where* to filter data:

```
Dictionary<int, string> secondDict = firstDict.Where(x => x.Value > 3)
.GroupBy(k => k.Value)
.ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => string.Join(",", g.Select(k => k.Key)));
```

### Update

For the Third dictionary:

```
Dictionary<int, string> thirdDict = secondDict
.Where(x => x.Value.Split(',').Length > 2 && x.Value.Split(',').Length <= 4)
.ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Value);
```

Comment: I tried this but the error stated was  CS0019 Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'int', and then tried to Parse but still cant have a successful run

Comment: What exactly do you want to compare?

Comment: from the second dictionary , I wanna check the total count of the strings. if count >2 && count <= 4 then the key and values would be copied / transferred to another dictionary. For eg.  key 1 has a c f i  so count is 4 hence they will be copied to another dict

Comment: I'll update the answer with a new solution for the third dictionary